# how to enable offline functionality for a single query on Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

In my application there are several requests that are made during execution and one that is made at the end. I would like the one that runs at the end to be sure to arrive, so I would like to enable offline functionality on this last request but not sure about the others. Is this possible and if so how to do it?

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to control offline availability on a granular level in the Firebase Realtime Database API. Offline disk caching is either on or off, and when it's on Firebase caches all recent data it receives, and all pending writes.